SMPS diode identification
It's marked T2D46 with a bar over the 46. It tests open both ways on a DMM diode test. I can't locate this with all of my google-fu powers or Octopart etc.
EDIT: I've included a picture of the board and where it connects:the anode of this diode connects to a TOP244Y switcher. It is from an iMac G5 SMPS.




Some indication of where it came from on a schematic of the PSU would help, is it a bypass diode, or surge diverted, or the switching diode, or...?

I'm working on reverse engineering for a schematic (it is from an iMac G5 SMPS - no schematics). That being said the anode is connected to a TOP244Y switcher. I added the picture to the original post.

Does this help? https://www.electronic-spare-parts.com/descript/t/t_2d.htm.  The suggestion there is that is a Zener.  (On various other sites I see that the digits after T2D are just a batch indication, and there is are hints that it's a 5V Zener but I wouldn't bank on it).

Being next to the standby flyback regulator, I'd be inclined to suspect zener -- definitely not 5V, not in that size -- but high voltage (200V or so), could be; see TOPSwitch application diagram. Hm, I suppose it could still be a low voltage zener if it was doing something like clamping aux output, but that would be after the aux rectifier.

Hm, I do find one service manual indicating a "B0BB17000009" labeled as "zener diode" (which other sources suggest is marked T2D), but I think this is only a Panasonic stock number, not a part they actually make. It seems likely to me, the T2D is a no-name Chinese part; good luck finding the original source--?

Here is an image from the datasheet showing the typical circuit (Figure 1), note that pin D is connected to the transformer and a voltage clamp network comprised of a diode plus zener diode:

Ref:
www.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/9/TOP242-250.pdf
Looking at the TOP244Y pinout (Figure 3 from the same datasheet), and referring to your photo, it seems this diode had its anode connected to pin D.

So, if the circuit of the PSU is wired as per the typical flyback configuration, then this would be a diode rated about 1A, probably over 400Vdc, and fast - but not necessarily ultra-fast.  One of the diodes from the UF400x series would probably be a good replacement, eg: UF4005 rated 600V, 1A.  See if the PSU has a zener diode as per Figure 1 of the datasheet, if so then confidence in this conclusion is increased.

The next component in series after this diode is a 10 ohm resistor (you can sort of see the green resistor in photo above) and from there to one of the HV caps.

OK.  Most likely this is still part of a voltage clamp, but one that uses an R instead of a zener.   Without a schematic I am only going by probabilities, not certainties.  This link may assist:  https://www.badcaps.net/forum/troubleshooting-hardware-devices-and-electronics-theory/troubleshooting-power-supplies-and-power-supply-design/12073-another-g5-661-3350-query?q=T2D46
